# How do I access the iPhone camera without the camera interface?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to access camera app inside the iPhone without having the camera interface shown, All that I need is to have my own design for the camera.
Actually I mean that I don't need to use the default camera app using the method "UIImagePickerController".
I like my camera shown up as it is in Instagram app for example.
Please help,, Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an AVCaptureSession and an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, as shown in this section of my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch30.html#_image_capture_with_av_foundation

You can build any interface around that.